# Document library error msg "This operation can only be performed on a file" when using Chinese characters in folder names...?

Tags: document-library, language

I'm receiving the following error when I create a subfolder using Chinese characters in a Sharepoint 2010 Foundation document library.

```
This operation can only be performed on a file
```

From the root folder, I can create one folder using a mix of English and Chinese characters, but no sub-folders will be created.

Is this due to lengths of the encoded URL string...?  Can I install a language pack or something...?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this that you could please provide? I'm not exactly sure how Chinese characters work in SP but you probably need to install the language pack.

Comment: We need more information to answer your question. Please [edit] your post and add details as requested by the community. It will be closed for now, but don't worry - once you have improved the question flag a moderator and it can be reopened. See [How do I ask questions here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) for general guidelines.